# Quartz Scheduler for java- How to run job every 5 minutes

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cron-task, crontrigger

Friends,
  I am using quartz scheduler for running a task every 5 minutes starting when application deployed & running continuously so i have written code as:

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sche = sf.getScheduler();

JobDetail job = newJob(RomeJob.class).withIdentity("Id1", "Rome").build();
CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("Id1Trigger", "Rome").withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?"))
.build();
sche.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
sche.start();
```

But its working sometime sometimes not. Please tell me whether i am missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways one of them is use trigger builder something like

```
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("mytrigger", "group1")
    .startNow()
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInMinutes(5)
            .repeatForever())
    .build();
```

Answer (score 14):

Instead of

```
0 0/5 * * * ?
```

use

```
0 */5 * * * *
```

**Edit:** This results in your task being run at 0 seconds of every minute that is divisible by 5.

**Edit 2:** `0/5` means only the minutes 0 and 5.

Comment: thanks for quick responce , but i want to run my task every 5 minutes continuously will you helo to figure out cron string for this

Comment: What do you mean by "every 5 minutes continuously"?

Comment: once i deploy my website on tomcat task should run continuously with interval of 5 minutes it should not stop until tomcat stop but with interval of 5 minutes

Comment: In latest version of Quartz: ' 0 */5 * * * ? '

Comment: @user2171669 Not everyone is running the latest version.  Our shop uses the top format.

Answer (score 8):

Do not use Cron schedule but simple schedule instead:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger().
  withIdentity("Id1Trigger", "Rome").
  withSchedule(
    simpleSchedule().
      withIntervalInMinutes(5).
      repeatForever()
  ).build();
```

Comment: +1 since the OP asked for "every 5 minutes starting when application deployed", not every 5 minutes on the wallclock.

Answer (score 0):

Now updated to new version!

```java
            /* Instantiate the job that will call the bot function */
            JobDetail jobSendNotification = JobBuilder.newJob(SendNotification.class)
                    .withIdentity("sendNotification")
                    .build();

            /* Define a trigger for the call */
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("sendEvery5Minutes")
                    .withSchedule(
                            SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForever(5))
                    .build();

            /* Create a scheduler to manage triggers */
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.getContext().put("bot", bot);
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobSendNotification, trigger);
```

Hope this will help someone find new the version. Send repeatMinute, repeatHourly